# How to get rid of closeworthy questions which do not get enough close votes because its tags are less active?

Tags: discussion

I maintain the [svg.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg.js) tag on Stack Overflow and try to make sure, that I answer questions tagged with [svg.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg.js) to my best knowledge or cast a close vote if they are not of any value.

Unfortunately svg.js is not that popular so it happens, that questions don't get closed because not enough votes are cast.

One example for such a question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516890/svg-js-doesnt-work) where the OP simply put the wrong path to the file.

Can this issue be solved somehow? Or will this question ghost on Stack Overflow for eternity?

Comment: You can always try the [Close Votes Review Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to get attention to things that need to be cleaned up, but make sure you read [their tour](https://socvr.org/tour) first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The close vote review queue provides a mechanism for questions that wouldn't normally be viewed by enough people to get closed to get enough attention to actually get closed.

The problem is that there just aren't enough people reviewing posts for closure *in general* to close all of the close-worthy questions that get posted to the site, so as a result, a large percentage of posts are not actually reviewed in that queue, simply because there are too many to review.  At this point it's not really a matter of site mechanisms, so much as it is just getting enough people willing to actually review questions for closure. (Possibly in combination with attempts to reduce the number of close-worthy questions being posted in the first place.)